# How can hashing Long ids to integer ids be safe?

Tags: java, hibernate

I just can't come up with a better solution than this.

Simple example: I have meals. Each meal has a description but those come in different languages. That is why a `MealDescription` consists of a primary key `(MealId, LanguageId)`. So far so good.

[This guide](http://java.boot.by/scbcd5-guide/ch05s03.html) here tells me that I have to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` but is it safe to do something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) mealId.hashCode() + languageId.hashCode();
}
```

if `mealId` and `languageId` are actually of type `Long` like they have to be since they are ids?

The guide I am referring to does the same:

```
private String name;
private long id;
// ..
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) name.hashCode() + id; 
}
```

So how does that work out?

Comment: Why would it be unsafe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045063/how-should-i-map-long-to-int-in-hashcode

Comment: The only big deal of having a lot of hash collisions would be an impact on performance as instead of getting the average case of O (1) you would get O (n) - worst case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hash, in principle, is less diverse than the object. you can have two or more objects mapped to the same hash. It is even legal (though very bad) to always return `0` from `hashCode()`

another example, the MD5 hash is 128 bits, no matter how long the message is.

Answer (score 2):

Always remember: `return 0` is *always* a valid implementation of `hashCode()`.  Hash codes aren't *supposed* to be unique, and this implementation does that just fine.

More or less, what you *want* from a `hashCode` implementation is just messing around with numbers until you get something fast to compute, `int`-shaped, deterministic based on the input, and is otherwise as messy as possible.  This is a perfectly fine implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your `mealId`/`languagId` are `Long`'s why would it be a problem to use their `hashCode()`s? That happens every day in a lot of Java code. Hash'es are most always shorter than the objects they stem from. The thing to "hope for" is that the risk for collision is small, and that risk does not get larger or smaller by adding two hashes as you do.

So, TL;DR, yes it's safe.

Cheers,