# What is needed to determine equality of an @Entity class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am doing some Springboot development, and wanted to know if it is safe to override only the `equals` method in order to determine equality. Specifically, the equality relies on the `petId` field of the `Pet` class (which is annotated with `@Entity`):

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PET_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long petId;
   /*getters and setters*/
```

I tested this and it works. The idea is that using this unique database generated ID, I can use equality to determine whether to update an existing record or create a new record, based on the `petId` value passed in from the PUT call containing a correctly formed `Pet` object in the request parameter, as below:

```
@CrossOrigin()
    @RequestMapping(value = "/equalitytest", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Pet getEquality(@RequestBody Pet inputPet) {

        Pet res = null;

        List<Pet> pets = petRepo.findAll();

        for (Pet p : pets) {

            if (inputPet.equals(p)) {
                res = p;
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Is this a wrong or inefficient approach? I have read that it is always best practice to override `hashCode` whenever `equals` is overridden, but I don't know if that is needed in this case/how it should be implemented.

Thank  you.

Comment: Always override `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString`, and if used, `compareTo` together and consistently. I recommend using natural keys for equality, following good object-oriented practice. Stay away from artificial "id" fields in an object model.

Comment: How can I use natural keys when they themselves could be updated? For example, there are two more fields in the `Pet` class, called `petName` and `petOwner`, and either of these could be updated, based on equality determined with another object's `petId` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think which isn't wrong or innefficient approch.

Below, a model for you follow:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (componentId != null ? componentId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the componentId fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Component)) {
        return false;
    }
    Component other = (Component) object;
    if ((this.componentId == null && other.componentId != null) || (this.componentId != null && !this.componentId.equals(other.componentId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.example.model.Component[ id=" + componentId + " ]";
}
```

PS. 1: In my case the model is called Component.

PS. 2: ...but, why you want know if your model is exists or not? The repositories in Spring Boot care for this detail on method [.save(Object object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420572/update-or-saveorupdate-in-crudrespository-is-there-any-options-available/24423508#24423508)

I hope help you!

Comment: Unfortunately, the hashCode does not work because it is of type `long` in my entity.

Comment: Thanks for the `.save`, it did exactly what I wanted. I tested by removing the equals method I wrote, so it used whatever underlying techniques to find and update the appropriate record in the db.

Comment: @ITWorker, you are welcome!
Another little thing about hashcode for Long  attributes... See if this answer help you to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4045101/2638434

Comment: You can't possibly based your `equals` and `hashCode` contract based on the entity's ID. Even less for this approach when the ID is auto-generated and will be `null` at the time the object is first created. Even though the `equals` contract accounts for it, it has some unneeded/unwanted complexity.

Comment: You can make a hash out of a `long` easily, @ITWorker. For example: `(int) ((id >> 23) ^ id)`, though that might not be a great one.

Answer (score 2):

Relying on a database identifier comparison (`petId` in your case) can get you into trouble if you use generated IDs (which is your case). Think about it; the identifier value won't be set before the object has been saved. It will only be set when `session.save()` is invoked on your transient object, making it persistent.

If you use manually assigned IDs, we can say you are not in trouble, you just have to make sure to set the identifier value before adding the object to the collection.

Moreover, you have to think what you are trying to achieve for that particular entity/object. There may be other fields (and this is usually the case) that you can count on to see if that object can be different or not.

For instance, imagine that you base your `equals` and `hashCode` contract on the entity ID and you are modeling a `Person {id, first_name, last_name, ssn}` object. If I provide you the same `first_name`, `last_name` and `ssn` for two records...aren't they equals indeed? But because you take into consideration only the entity ID, the won't be.

About overriding `equals` and `hashCode`, Hibernate [has a nice](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode) (but long) description of how to do it and when to do it.

Comment: Please see my edit of the controller code to see what the equality is used for. Using the `Person` example you wrote, what if the first_name, last_name, and ssn of a person all have to be changed? How would you determine the incoming object's equality with the the object that already exists in the database?

Comment: You search by ID in that case, since you want to update something in particular. Like I said, it depends on what you refer by "equality".

Comment: Int IDs in a database are a _surrogate key_. They are not there to identify the entity associated with a table row. They are there as a surrogate, as the name says, for the _natural key_, the identity determinant in the modeled domain. They exist to speed up database operations, not to model identity. They are not durable in the face of change, so just drop that line. If you read up on database theory, you'll find that the identifier problem has many strategies, none perfect. One thing is clear, though. If you cannot model equality with domain-relevant data, surrogate IDs will not help you.